# How can i replace a character with blank space in bash using jq library

Tags: json, regex, bash, shell, jq

I am using `jq` command to replace "value" for corresponding "key" in a JSON file.
Here in the following code snippet I have to replace `v`'s value corresponding to key `k` in the JSON object `node`.

```
  jq --arg flag "$node" \
                   --arg temp  $v \
             '(.[$flag]|.['$k'])|=$temp' properties.json > tempprop.json
```

The problem is if there is already a value is present then I need to pass an empty string as value. But `jq` parser is throwing exception saying

```
jq: error: properties/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
properties.json
```

So I don't know any other way to deal with this, appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `v` is an empty string, you need to quote its expansion. You should pass the value of `$k` via a variable as well, rather than attempting to interpolate it.

```
jq --arg flag "$node" \
   --arg temp  "$v" \
   --arg k1 "$k" \
   '(.[$flag]|.[$k1])|=$temp' properties.json > tempprop.json
```

As is, the unquoted expansion of empty `$v` "disappears", and `jq` sees the filter as the second argument to that `--arg` option, leaving `properties.json` to be interpreted as the filter.